# min-width for wrapper DIV not working

Tags: css, css-float

I've two floated DIVs (two columns) which are nested in an "clear-float"-DIV, which itself is nested in an centered DIV ("wrapper" DIV).

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="block2">
        <div id="slot_left">
            CONTENT-LEFT
        </div>
        <div id="slot_right">
            *CONTENT-RIGHT*
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The right column has `min-width` and `max-width` CSS option set. But the wrapper DIV, which has `min-width` and `max-width` also, is always expanded to max width.

```
#content {
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 80px;
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #c00;
}
.block {
    overflow: hidden;
    _overflow: visible;
    _overflow-x: hidden;
    _height: 0;
}
#slot_left {
    width: 200px;
    background: #ff0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#slot_right {
    float: left;
    background: #cc0;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
```

What's the reason for that? I want the wrapper DIV to has minimum width required but to be centered on screen.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sHB7g/) is an fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/sHB7g/1/

```
#content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and then added a content wrapper

```
#contentwrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

the html then is like this

```
  <div id="contentwrapper">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="block">
            <div id="slot_left">
                CONTENT-LEFT
            </div>
            <div id="slot_right">
                *CONTENT-RIGHT*
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I prefer your solution, because it does not affect `block` class and adds missing outer wrapping DIV to center content again.

Answer (score 4):

use `display:inline-block`

**why this is happening??** `div` is by default block level element, so when you have given `max-width`, it will always obey it to occupy max area possible....

**http://jsfiddle.net/sHB7g/3/**

**CSS**

```
#content {
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 80px;
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #c00;
    display:inline-block
}
.block {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```